Python checking if a curve is below of above an envelope line
I have an envelope defined by its corner points (linear in between) and want to check if a curve coming from a measurement is below this envelope. The curve may have 1000 data points but the envelop has intially only the four corner points (as shown in the figure).
How can I check if the curve is not intersecting the envelop?


How would you do it without Python? What part of doing the same with Python is specifically giving you problems?

You could "render out" the envelope to a list/array of points the same length as the curve, subtract the two from each other and see if the result always has the same sign.

Bolzano's theorem. Substract the envelope Y value from the curve Y value. Then iterate over the result and if there's a change in sign it means a crossing.

I posted an answer to do it by hand, but actually it seems easier to use numpy.interp to interpolate the envelope so it has points at the same x-coordinates as the curve.

As @Stef already pointed out, you can optimize it with Python using numpy.interp. The important step is to interpolate it to match the resolution of your measurement curve:
import numpy as np

envelope_corners = [(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 0)]
curve_x = np.linspace(0,3,100)
curve_y = 0.2 + 0.8 * np.sin(curve_x)

envelope_x, envelope_y = zip(*envelope_corners)

# Use numpy's interp function for interpolation
interpolated_envelope = np.interp(curve_x, envelope_x, envelope_y)

tolerance = 1e-9
is_below = np.all(np.array(curve_y) <= interpolated_envelope + tolerance)

print("Curve is below envelope:", is_below)


Curve is below envelope: False

Example:

UPDATE
As requested, here is the code to create the plot:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))

plt.plot(envelope_x, envelope_y, 'ro-', label='Envelope Corners')
plt.plot(curve_x, interpolated_envelope, 'r--', label='Interpolated Envelope')
plt.plot(curve_x, curve_y, 'b-', label='Curve')

plt.title(f"Curve {'is' if is_below else 'is not'} below the envelope")
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)

plt.fill_between(curve_x, curve_y, interpolated_envelope, 
                    where=(np.array(curve_y) <= interpolated_envelope),
                    color='g', alpha=0.3, label='Area Below Envelope')
plt.fill_between(curve_x, curve_y, interpolated_envelope, 
                    where=(np.array(curve_y) > interpolated_envelope),
                    color='r', alpha=0.3, label='Area Above Envelope')

plt.legend()
plt.show()


Pretty cool picture, can you include the code you used to get it?

Upvoted. I suggest replacing curve = ...; curve_x, curve_y = zip(*curve) with curve_x = np.linspace(0,3,100); curve_y = 0.2 + 0.8 * np.sin(curve_x).

Yeah, that makes more sense, thx :)

For every point (x,y) in the curve, find the two surrounding corner points (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) in the envelope.
The corresponding point in the envelope will be at (x,Y) with Y given by
Y = y1 + (x - x1) * (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)

Thus (x,y) is below the envelope if and only if:
y <= y1 + (x - x1) * (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)


Interpolate the envelope using numpy.interp so that you get a different representation of the same envelope that matches the x-coordinates of your curve.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

envelope_x = np.array([0,1,2,3.2])
envelope_y = np.array([0.3,1.2,1.2,0])

curve_x = np.linspace(0, 3.5, 100)
curve_y = np.sin(curve_x)

plt.plot(envelope_x, envelope_y)
plt.plot(curve_x, curve_y)
plt.show()

resampled_envelope_y = np.interp(curve_x, envelope_x, envelope_y)

print((resampled_envelope_y - curve_y >= 0).all())
# True


